# Call function (which generates list to be shown) for each character entered into TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I want my GUI to update and react to values that the user types into a TextField as it is typed in. I have a function that calculates the result as an array of strings, which is then displayed.

However, I have not been able to achieve this - currently I have had to resort to a submit button that the user has to press when finished entering the value.

So, is there a way to react on each digit entered? Please see my example code!

First the simple GUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var initialValue = ""
@ObservedObject var model = ImmediateUpdaterModel()
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        TextField("Enter value", text: $initialValue)
        Button(
            action: {model.PopulateListBasedOnInputValue(inputValue:  convertTextToDouble(inputString: initialValue))
            },
            label: {Text("Submit")}
            )
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(model.displayData,id: \.self) { myString in
                    Text("\(myString)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the ViewModel containing the function PopulateListBasedOnInputValue:

```
class ImmediateUpdaterModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var displayData = [String]()

func PopulateListBasedOnInputValue(inputValue: Double) {
    displayData.removeAll()
    if inputValue<10 {
        displayData.append("That is a low value")
    } else if inputValue<100 {
        displayData.append("That is a medium value")
    } else if inputValue<1000 {
        displayData.append("That is a high value")
    }
    displayData.append("However, all values are good!")

init() {
    displayData = []
}
```

**Final clarification of what I want to achieve:
If the user aims to write 999, first this is displayed:**

That is a low value

However, all values are good!

**When the next digit is entered, the text changes to**

That is a medium value

However, all values are good!

**And when the final 9 is entered the text changes to**

That is a high value

However, all values are good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `ImmediateUpdaterModel` is complicating the situation. You *could* get it to work by triggering `PopulateListBasedOnInputValue` using `onChange` or even `Combine`, but it seems like the whole thing could be simplified by just building it into the `View`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textValue = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter value", text: $textValue)
            ScrollView {
                if !textValue.isEmpty {
                    if let doubleValue = Double(textValue) {
                        switch doubleValue {
                        case _ where doubleValue < 10:
                            Text("That is a low value")
                        case _ where doubleValue < 100:
                            Text("That is a medium value")
                        case _ where doubleValue >= 100:
                            Text("That is a high value")
                        default:
                            Text("")
                        }
                        Text("However, all values are good!")
                    } else {
                        Text("Invalid character")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also separate the logic out into a computed property which would get re-run each time the `@State` changes. This strategy looks a little closer to your original system:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textValue = ""
    
    var displayedData : [String] {
        var toReturn = [String]()
        if !textValue.isEmpty {
            if let doubleValue = Double(textValue) {
                switch doubleValue {
                case _ where doubleValue < 10:
                    toReturn.append("That is a low value")
                case _ where doubleValue < 100:
                    toReturn.append("That is a medium value")
                case _ where doubleValue >= 100:
                    toReturn.append("That is a high value")
                default:
                    break
                }
                toReturn.append("However, all values are good!")
            } else {
                toReturn.append("Invalid character")
            }
        }
        return toReturn
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter value", text: $textValue)
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(displayedData, id: \.self) { item in //generally, you want to avoid using \.self as an id, but here we can guarantee all of the strings are unique
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, jndpx! I have implemented the second method that you proposed, and it works, even in the much more complicated calculation methods in my app. This is a wonderful community - I hope that I can contribute to it as I learn more..